# How to enable snap nodes in Inkscape 0.91?

Tags: vector, inkscape, snapping

I have seen in Inkscape tutorials that there was a snap bar; A tool bar with a bunch of easily accessible/toggle-able settings for snapping.

Does it still exist? If so, how can I enable it?
If not, what is the equivalent in Inkscape 0.91?

Comment: Why the downvote? I couldn't find it either and ended up here from Google.

Answer (score 3):

Oops, it is vertical on the right side. So I found it, and the snap bar still exists